# How to change the name of a label?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

I'd like to know how to rename the labels in Trello.

They all have been named as their color, as a default, and I'd like to change it so it's easier to find out which is labeling what.

In the Trello development board you've done it. That's why I'm asking how...

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the board in Trello
2. Click on the "Board Profile" button on the right, **or** on the title of the board (the one in the upper left).  A dialog will open.
3. Click the "Labels" link (on the right of the dialog)
4. Click to on a label to rename it

Comment: Or click on Board Profile after step # 1 - then do steps 3 & 4.